# User disobeying rules?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers

So last question that I posted. i.e : [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16503/answer-posting-method), I wanted to ask because a specific new user whom I have warned almost on all answer he has posted (5-6) was not following, yet he keeps answering with **snippets** and won't even reply to to comments.

So far 2 of his/her answers (they were on my challenges), I have had them deleted by voting. I am curious on what the mod take on that is ?

Are users allowed to continuously keep posting rubbish answers to challenges and we keep deleting them. All answers he posted ended in the low quality review (I know that since I reviewed most of 'em) and I am getting tired of telling him that.

I would like to know any policy on that or should I simply let him answer and mark his answers as ok on the low quality post queues ?

---

User's name and profile not linked since I have no right to do that.

> innocent until proven guilty

rule applies

Comment: The user will eventually get answer-banned.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer : and in the mean time...

Comment: And in the mean time you continue to flag them as normal, until they get banned?  There's not really much **you** can do to stave off junk posts, other than flag them accordingly.  Non-moderators don't have much else they *can* do, and eventually the user will get answer-banned with enough flagged/deleted posts.

Comment: @ThomasWard : okay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the first answer, post a **[nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)** comment, explaining why their post is invalid, and linking them to the relevant meta posts. Remember that this is most likely a new user, and you are representing the site to them.

On all future interactions, flag it, cast a delete vote if you can, and move on. If it's really invalid, it will end up deleted. If not, you can ask about a specific case on meta.

> whom I have warned almost on all answer he has posted

Don't do this. One comment is plenty. Feel free to go through and flag all the posts, but beyond that it's out of your hands. The community review queue or us mods will take it from there.

Commenting on every single one of their posts is unnecessary. Saying *How many times do I need to tell you*, or *This is the fifth time I am telling you* is agressive and borderline harassment. Calling their answers "rubbish" is similarly hostile.

> I am getting tired of telling him that

Than stop telling them! If you are frustrated by another user, you don't have to say anything to them.